# Submit form using Ajax/Jquery and check result?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am wanting to submit a form using ajax to go to my page 'do_signup_check.php'.

There it will check the email address the user entered against the database to see if there is a match.

If there is a match I want my ajax form to redirect the user to the login.php page.

If there isn't a match I want it to load my page 'do_signup.php'

for some reason the code seems to be doing nothing. Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

My Ajax form:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
  </script>

  <?php include 'assets/config.php'; ?>

  <script>
    $(function () {

      $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'do_signup_check.php',
          data:{"name":name,"email":email},
          success: function () {
            if(result == 0){    
              $('.signup_side').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
              $('.signup_side').load('do_signup.php',function(){}).hide().fadeIn(500);
            });

            }else{
              $('.signup_side').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
              $('.signup_side').load('login.php',function(){}).hide().fadeIn(500);
            }
          });
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sign_up_contain">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="signup_side">    
          <h3>Get Onboard.</h3>    
          <h6>Join the directory.</h6>

          <form id="signup" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false">
            <div class="signup_row action">
              <input type="text" placeholder="What's your Name?" name="name" id="name" class="signup" autocomplete="new-password" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" required />
              <input type="text" placeholder="Got an Email?" name="email" id="email" class="signup" autocomplete="new-password" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" required />
              <div class="g-recaptcha" style="margin-top:30px;" data-sitekey="6LeCkZkUAAAAAOeokX86JWQxuS6E7jWHEC61tS9T"></div>
              <input type="submit" class="signup_bt" name="submit" id="submt" value="Create My Account">
            </div> 
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Do_Signup_Check.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();        
require 'assets/connect.php';

$myName = $_POST["name"];
$myEmail = $_POST["email"];

$check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_verification WHERE email='".$myEmail."'");

if (!$check) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); 
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '0';
}
?>
```

Comment: Use login and signup model instead. if the response is a success then the login model is shown through JQuery $('#loginModel').modal('show');  and if it fails then signup model is shown through JQuery $('#suignupModel').modal('show');

Answer (score 0):

After receiving success in Ajax and doing all necessary logic (fadeOut etc) just relocate user to login.php:

```
window.location.href = 'path/to/login.php';
```

Otherwise, in error function (it is goes just after success function) do the next:

```
window.location.href = 'path/to/do_signup.php';
```

**Upd:**
In case you want to have some piece of code from another file, you can use jQuery method **load**.

```
$('#some-selector').load('path/to/course/login.php');
```

It's a very basic example of using 'load', go google around it to explore more.

Comment: I don't want a simple redirect. The loging.php page needs to load via ajax in a div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use input id 'submt' to trigger the form as such :

```js
$("#submt").click(function(){

          e.preventDefault();
          
          //your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the jquery in your page, the function is also missing the closing parentheses.

Include the jquery at the top

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Replace your function with the following code:-

```
 <script>
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {alert(123);

      e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'receive-callback.php',
            data:{"name":name,"email":email},
            success: function () {
                if(result == 0){    
                    $('.signup_side').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
                        $('.signup_side').load('do_signup.php',function(){}).hide().fadeIn(500);
                    });
                }else{
                    $('.signup_side').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
                        $('.signup_side').load('login.php',function(){}).hide().fadeIn(500);
                    });
                }
            }
         });

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this code.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'do_signup_check.php',
        data:{"name":name,"email":email},
        success: function (result) {
        if(result == 0){ 
           window.location.href = 'do_signup.php';
        }else{
           window.location.href = 'login.php';
        }

      });
```

My Do_Signup_Check.php page:

```
<?php
    session_start();        
    require 'assets/connect.php';


    $myName=$_POST["name"];
    $myEmail=$_POST["email"];

    $check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_verification WHERE email='".$myEmail."'");

    if (!$check) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); 
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0){    
       echo json_encode(array('result'=>'1'));
       exit;    
    }else{    
      echo json_encode(array('result'=>'0'));
      exit;
    }

?>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a high level description about the OPs problem and how your example solves it?

Comment: Did you test the code? In JS part you would need to check the response like `result.result == 0` in your case.